# PHP require_once persists in a separate process

Tags: php

EDIT: I need to provide more detail, not sure what is going on.

I seem to be having a problem where PHP treats a require_once in a separate process as a repeat of the require in the outer process.

Suppose I have this file which I will run on the CLI:

```
<?php

require_once 'includeme.php';

$command = "php runme.php";
$handle = popen($command, 'r');
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
$exit = pclose($handle);

print_r($read);
```

This does the following:

1. include a file
2. run a child process, which will also try to include that file.

The file includeme.php is this:

```
<?php

print "I was included";
```

Including it should just cause it to return that string.

The runme.php file is this:

```
<?php

$result = require_once 'includeme.php';
print $result;
```

Running the main script produces this output:

```
I was included
1
```

What seems to be happening is that the runme.php script is getting a 1 for the require_once statement, which is what  require_once returns **if the script has already been included**.

But runme.php is a separate process. How can PHP be thinking it's already included includeme.php?

Comment: Interesting question. Should `fread` get `STDOUT`, signal or `STDERR` here?

Comment: As an experiment - if you changed the first script to `echo require_once 'includeme.php';`, what does it show?

Comment: I'm running it again and it's now producing the expected result. Not sure what is going on. Will investigate further.

Comment: I'm going to request to delete this, as my example code is now working as expected. The problem I am having is to do with when the require_once() is the Composer autoloader, and the inner script fails to get the returned autoloader object. I'll keep working on isolating the problem.

Comment: Ok yes, please could an admin delete this. I was barking up the wrong tree completely, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1

The `1` in your output does not indicate it was already previously included, just that it was included successfully.

Regardless of the return value, you can use `require_once` everywhere and trust it's working as expected.

Comment: I specifically need the return value because what I am really trying to load is the Composer autoloader, which returns the autoloader object, and I need that object for the inner script.

Comment: The docs for include_once say:

```
The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns TRUE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do note that `require_once` (like, require, include...) is **a construct**, not PHP function. So, returned `1` probably means, OK, file is included. No idea why echoed `I was included` was not caught.